# Why it is showing -- "The argument type 'User' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'User1' in flutter"

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I get the below error when I run the code, Pls help me

error: The argument type 'User' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'User1'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [time_tracker_app] lib\services\auth.dart:34)

here is my code :

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class User1 {
  User1({@required this.uid, });
  final String uid;
}

abstract class AuthBase {
  Future<User1> currentUser();
  Future<User1> signInAnonymously();
  Future<void> signOut();
}

class Auth implements AuthBase {
  final _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  User1 _userFromFirebase(User1 user) {
    if (user == null) {
      return null;
    }

    return User1(uid: user.uid);
  }

  @override
  Future<User1> currentUser() async {
    final user = _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
    return _userFromFirebase(User1(uid: user.uid));
  }

  @override
  Future<User1> signInAnonymously() async {
    final  authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInAnonymously();
     return _userFromFirebase(authResult.user);
  }

  Future<void> signOut() async {
    await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the `_userFromFirebase` function parameter. From the `signInAnonymously` function you are calling the _userFromFirebase function with Firebase User object.

```dart
@override
Future<User1> signInAnonymously() async {
   final  authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInAnonymously();
   return _userFromFirebase(authResult.user); // Passing User object
}
```

To fix the issue, you need to change the parameter type:

```dart
User1 _userFromFirebase(User user) {
   if (user == null) {
      return null;
   }
   return User1(uid: user.uid);
}
```